# Terminating app due to uncaught exception Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I currently have login authentication working, as well as registration with firebase. I now wanted to keep my user logged in, which is working. The problem I am facing is when I log out, I try to log back in and I receive this error:
// Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'chatRoom''\
Which does not make sense, because when I first log in, it brings me to the ChatRoom Viewcontroller using the chatRoom segue.

This is my code below:

```
 func handleLogin() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text
            else {
            print("Form is not valid")
            return
        }
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                self.loginErrorAlert("Error!", message: "Username or password incorrect, please try again.")
                return
            }
            // successfully logged in our user and keep user logged in until they logout
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, forKey: "loggedIn")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatRoom", sender: self)// this is the error I am facing
            }
        })
    }
    func handleRegister() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text else {
            print("Form is not valid")
            signupErrorAlert("Error!", message: "Could not be Registered at this time, please try again.")
            return
        }
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: User?, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                self.loginErrorAlert("Error!", message: "Could not be Registered at this time, please try again later.")
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else {
                return
            }
            // successfully authenticated user and keep logged in until they logout
            let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://boccighub.firebaseio.com/")
            let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
            let values = ["name": name, "email": email]
            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if err != nil {
                    print(err!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, forKey: "loggedIn")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatRoom", sender: self)
                }
            })
        })
    }
    // User logged out
    @IBAction func handleLogout(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            print("user signedout")

            if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
                print("No user, key removed")
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "loggedIn")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                print("User logged out")
                let loginController = LoginViewController()
                present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } catch let logoutError {
            print(logoutError)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with your title

Comment: @J.Doe is that better?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with logging out, and Firebase. Your title is very misleading.

Comment: The error could make sense because when you log out, you do `let loginController = LoginViewController(), then present(...)` and you don't call the `LoginViewController` which is in the Storyboard with the `segue`. Well, it "could make sense", but it's lacking the info from what class is that code, etc.

Comment: @Larme ok would you like me to upload my loginViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I Removed the let loginController = LoginViewController(), 
I created a new segue and now do self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logOut", sender: self), works perfectly